# how to create file object in js?

Tags: javascript, file

I get from the server an object that should represent a file, and it looks like this:

```
name: "סריקה0252.pdf",
url: "https:XYZ/ABC/1/סריקה0252_28-05-2019_11:24:40.pdf"
```

Now, I want to convert it to a [file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File) of `JavaScript` ,

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: do you mean you would like `js` to parse this?  or you want an actual file `myfile.js`?  if you want an actual file you would need a server sided language.

Comment: See [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob).

Comment: you can convert this file to the blob. from that file url.

Comment: @Ashish, Can you demonstrate how?

Comment: @BaruchG. posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function urlToBlob(url){
 return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( "GET", url, true );
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function( e ) {
        resolve(this.response)
    };
    xhr.onerror = function( error ){
        reject(error)
    }
    xhr.send();
 })
}
let fileUrl = "https:XYZ/ABC/1/סריקה0252_28-05-2019_11:24:40.pdf"
urlToBlob(fileUrl).then(function(blob){
  console.log(blob)
  // you will get blob object of that file here
})
```

Here is the function to convert it. this will load the file first to the local. once it will be loaded, it will return blob object as return type is defined as a blob.